# Powershell updating mobile phone field

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, bamboo

I am updating all employees in Azure AD fields to have the same data from bamboo HR
but when I try to update the mobile phone it shows me an error do anyone have solution?

I tried this code to update the job title and display name and its works

**Update-AzADUser -UPNOrObjectId $UserPrincipalName -JobTitle $jobTitle**

but there is nothing called -Mobilephone

Answer (score 0):

That field does seem to be missing as an option on `Update-AzADUser` but there is a `-Mobile` parameter on `Set-AzureADUser` from the AzureAD module. Once you have that installed, try:

```
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserPrincipalName -JobTitle $jobTitle -Mobile $Mobile
```

-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0

Comment: The term 'Set-AzureADUser' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling
     | of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: the only modules that works with me = Update-AzADUser & Set-AzADUser and the set also doesn't have the option -mobile

Comment: You need to install AzureAD via `install-module azuread`

Comment: I have install it but it shows same error msg I think because of the new update?